# How to convert a SAS retain in Teradata sql?

Tags: sql, sas, teradata

I'm trying to convert SAS code into Teradata and I'm struggling how to convert the code below. The issue is how to convert the retain statement into sql.

** Datastep code

```
data test2;
  set test1;
  by name_id;
  format counter 8.0;
  retain counter year_counter;
  if first.name_id then do;
    counter = month_start;
    year_counter=year_start;
  end;
  else counter=counter+1;
  if(counter=13) then do;
    counter=1;
    year_counter=year_counter+1;
  end;
  mmyy_counter=compress(counter|"/"|year_counter);
  mmyy=compress(month|"/"|year);
run;
```

**Data

```
name_id  month_start  month_year
12131as  07           2010
12132ab  02           2003
```

**My thoughts

I was thinking of putting this in a procedure, although I'm not sure how.
Another possibility is to use row_number, but again I am not sure how to start.

Comment: This would be much easier to understand if you explained the logic and provided the desired output.

Comment: Code conversion is explicitly off topic for Stack Overflow.  Ask your question in such a manner as it is not a code conversion (ie, explain what you want as Gordon requested in context) if you wish it answered.  You may provide the `SAS` code as clarification or additional information, but it may not be the primary question.